# Hibernate auto generate second id

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Suppose that I have a table with only two columns ID and Car, and the Car column can have repeated values, for example:

```
id | car

1 | 200

2 | 200

3 | 201

4 | 201

5 | 201

6 | 202
```

I need a new column which automatically generates a second id grouped by Cars when new records are inserted, something that looks like this:

```
id | car | second_id

1 | 200 | 1

2 | 200 | 2

3 | 201 | 1

4 | 201 | 2

5 | 201 | 3

6 | 202 | 1
```

I've tried something like this but does not work:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "car")
private int car;

@GeneratedValue(generator="second_id")
@GenericGenerator(name="second_id", strategy="com.example.SecondIdGenerator")
@Column(name = "second_id", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 20)
private int secondId;
```

SecondIdGenerator class for now only returns a fixed value for test, but this value is not showing in the db, in other words, it is not working.

How i do this? 
Hibernate has something for this?

(I'm using MySQL db)

Comment: Question: will it be possible to change car value (update query) after created ? If so, i guess we'll need to recalculate the second id, right ?

Comment: @Bruno No! Car value can't be changed!

Comment: You don't tell us what problem you really are trying to solve. You might try asking a separate question with the issue that led you to this question.

Comment: @Rob I need to do this because each car has a independency, so when I get all records of a car I need a internal id of this records (a second id grouped by car). I know some ways to do this, but I would to know if exists something automatic provided by Hibernate

Comment: There isn't anything automatic provided by hibernate for this situation. You either do a logic before you persist the object and determine the value for the second_id or, if you don't care about the value of the second_id, you only need it to be different, then you could use the @prepersist and maybe for the second_id just give it the time in milliseconds. it will be different id's and they will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unaware of any tool support for this sort of column.

You can implement calculation of the value for the second_id column with a trigger. You would probably want a "before insert" trigger. The trigger would find the existing maximum second_id for the car that is being inserted and add one for the new row's second_id value. If you allow updates to the car column, you could support recalculation of the second_id column in the same way (although this would leave holes in the second_id sequence for the prior car value's second_id column).

You might find it easier to create a stored procedure that encapsulates the business logic if you are going to have multiple triggers that maintain the column value.

You would also want to have a unique constraint on (car, second_id). If you don't do this, you will get duplicates whenever you have multiple clients insert rows with the same car value. The unique constraint will only allow the first to commit to finish successfully. All other concurrent transactions that tried to insert a row with the same car value (and computed the same second_id value) will fail. Obviously, you need to handle this exception in the client by cleaning up and retrying the transaction.

Comment: I understand, but can I do this using Hibernate? Maybe using @GeneratedValue without a @Id?

Comment: Hibernate does not have a way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

at run time if there is no @Id specified hibernate will get an exception , i think you can change the structure of your table.